# Why are there two list types in ATS: list and list0?

Tags: ats

In ATS code, I often see two list types: list and list0. What is the difference between them?

Comment: There is actually another one: list_vt for linear lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `list`, if you peek at its defintion, is length-indexed.

The type `list0` is not.

Sometimes when programming, excessive precision is too costly in terms of productivity. In these cases, `list0` may be preferable to use over `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, `list`-values and `list0`-values have the very same representation.

You can use `g0ofg1_list` to turn a `list`-value into a `list0`-value and `g1ofg0_list` to turn a `list0`-value into a `lis`t-value. Note that `g0ofg1` and `g1ofg0` are overloaded with `g0ofg1_list` and `g1ofg0_list`, respectively. Similar functions include `g0ofg1_int` / `g1ofg0_int` and `g0ofg1_string` / `g1ofg0_string`.